# how to make animation app in java using applet,awt and swing?

Tags: java, swing, animation, applet, awt

i want to make an app in java which will run on browsers like following links:

1. http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/geometric-optics/geometric-optics_en.html
2. http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/ray-diagrams.html

i am new in programming.
how can i start creating it in java?

Please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) which has an example of a Swing Applet with animation.

> i am new in programming.

It won't hurt to read the rest of the tutorial as well since it contains most everything you want to know about Swing.